# xarray, indexing with multidimensional coordinates

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I'm not sure if it is possible, but I would like to add a new coordinate to a xarray which is the same size as the data that its indexing, but has a different number of dimensions.

For example, take a 2D array, one dimension is a date, and the other is time of day:

```py
data = np.random.rand(5, 24)
date_idx = pd.date_range("20200921", "20200925")
time_of_day_idx = np.arange(0, np.timedelta64(1, "D"), np.timedelta64(1, "h"))

da = xr.DataArray(data,
                  dims=("date", "time_of_day"),
                  coords={"date" : date_idx,
                          "time_of_day": time_of_day_idx})
```

I can add a new 2D coordinate with the times for each value in the array.

```py
time_idx = np.add.outer(date_idx, time_of_day_idx)
da.assign_coords(time=(("date", "time_of_day"), time_idx))
```

But what I'd really like to be able to do is to stack the dimensions together to create a new one dimensional coordinate for a time-series in the same array, something like this:

```py
da.assign_coords(time=(("date", "time_of_day"), time_idx.flatten()))
```

However, doing this raises:

```
ValueError: dimensions ('date', 'time_of_day') must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=1
```

I know I can reshape or flatten a 2D xarray to 1D and create the new index for the time-series but it would be really handy to be able to have a 1D coordinate that can index into a 2D xarray.  I've played a bit with stacking and MultiIndex, but I found the same problem, each index has separate values access each dimension, rather than a single value that can be used to index the location across both dimensions.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the dimensions of the array _and_ the coord? Or have an array with a differently dimensioned coord?

Comment: @Maximilian Ideally I'd like have an array that can be indexed by a coordinate that has different dimensions.  In my example, I could have a time series stored in a 2D array, on one axis is date and another axes is time of day.  I'd like to be able to specify a 1D coordinate called time, that can index across both of these axes.

Comment: What do you mean by "a 1D coordinate ... that can index across both of these axes"?

Comment: @Maximilan Sorry I'm not explaining well. Say I have a 2D xarray, one axis is 3 long, the other is 4 long.  I'd like to have add a coordinate which is 12 long. This is like DataArray.stack(), but I'd like to set a single value at each index instead of a MultiIndex has multiple values at each index.

Maybe this is possible another way, eg. creating a new MultiIndex coordinate by stacking and then adding another coordinate with its own set of values that references this MultiIndex coordinate? Can coordinates in xarrays index each other, or can they only index the axes in the array directly?

Comment: What would you like your final array to look like? 3x4 or 12x1? Xarray only allows indexes along each dimension in the array, so you can't have a 12x1 index on a 4x3 array. [cont]

Comment: Is the question "Can I combine the levels in a MultiIndex into a single Index?"

Comment: I don't want to change the shape of array, but I would to be able index a 2D array with a 1D coordinate, so yes another way be to "combine the levels in a MultiIndex into a single Index" as you say.

Comment: OK, that's not possible, unfortunately

Comment: @Maximilian,  Thanks for answering my question, it would make a nice feature, I guess a more general description is to allow a coordinate that is a different 'view' of the array (but of the same data).

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with xarrays.